# sharepoint: Using a Content Editor Web Part this error occurred:"Cannot retrieve properties at this time."

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, content-editor

I have a content editor web part. Whenever I edit the content and then click save, the following errors occurred:

```
"Cannot retrieve properties at this time."
"Cannot save your changes"
```

How do you fix this?

I tried googling it.. there are some similar cases but not exactly the same. I tried this link:

[www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_21975446.html](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_21975446.html)

and this one:

[support.microsoft.com/kb/830342](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830342)

and this one:

[blogs.msdn.com/gyorgyh/archive/2009/03/04/troubleshooting-web-part-property-load-errors.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/gyorgyh/archive/2009/03/04/troubleshooting-web-part-property-load-errors.aspx)

Comment: Does this keep happening even after an IISReset / app pool recycle?

Comment: Have you installed the latest service pack, like the Microsoft KB suggests? Installing the latest patches solves many of these issues, specially when there's no code involved.

Comment: And include the latest Cumulative Update (April 2009 i believe is the latest)

Comment: Do you have any other Web Part on the page? If so, try to isolate this issue by removing the other ones.

Comment: Is it possible to send the error log written in Log file under 12 hive

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer!! apparently using mozilla firefox it worked. Then I found out that there is a javascript error in IE, this javascript error doesnt happened in firefox. how ironic!

Comment: I feel dirty having to use Firefox to work on a MS product, but it does work.

Comment: I just got this error in FF on OS X. Worked for me in Safari, so the fact that it's a browser issue did help, though the browsers with this issue may not be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing anything to modify the URL in an HTTPModule?  I ran into this problem on a publishing site where a module was hiding the "/pages" part of the URL.  Modifying the CEWP via the page when accessed w/o the "/Pages" wasn't working, but with the "/Pages" it was.

Example:

Got error: http://www.tempura.org/webpartpage.aspx
Worked: http://www.tempuri.org/pages/webpartpage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is an answer -- "don't use IE".

In my case (and apparently many others) it has something to do with ISA + SharePoint + host headers. I will post the fix if I find one.

Comment: see this forum post for more detailed information: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/d5514843-98a3-4ae2-8241-403e12d30183

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with this before and have found recycling the Application Pool often corrects the problem.

Rodney

Answer (score 0):

IE8 -->

Tools --> Compatiblity View Settings --> CHECK THIS : Display All Websites in ....

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a webpart page, make sure that it is checked out. Sometimes the document library the webpart pages are in will have a "force check out to edit" option and it will give you errors if the webpage itself isn't checked out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error recently.  In javascript, I had written some **prototype** overrides (see examples below) to add some custom functions to the string and array objects.  Both of these overrides interferred with SharePoint's native JavaScript somehow in IE.  I removed the references from the master page and this issue was **FIXED**.  Currently trying to find a work-around so I can keep them because things like the `string.format` function is *very* nice to have...

```
//Trim
if (typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
     String.prototype.trim = function(){
         return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
     }
 }

//Format
String.format = function() { 
  var s = arguments[0]; 
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {        
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");              
    s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]); 
  } 


  return s; 
}
```

Comment: I think the problem you are running into has to do with SharePoint has code that uses for in without testing for hasOwnProperty(). I ran into this adding to Array. Apparently in 2007, MS was still of the opinion that nobody would ever use .prototype ...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Finally it worked for me using url /Pages/Contact-Us.aspx instead of clean URL. It worked only with IE browser. Don't know why this was happening but anyhow it worked with me.

- Use IE browser
- Use Pages in the URLinstead of clean URL.

Answer (score 0):

to me,
compatibility mode in IE8, to work