# HTML Form Web Part shows "cannot retrieve properties at this time" while trying to save changes

Tags: sharepoint-2013

While im trying to save changes to HTML Form Web Part message appears "cannot retrieve properties at this time" and "cannot save changes" right after it. I've searched internet ... but there is no real solution.

So, what i've got :

Sharepoint 2013 foundation, latest updates ( RU )

No errors in events, nothing special in ULS ( except annoying "Forced due to logging gap", dont know what to do with this btw))

In IIS all bindings added, all AAM paths are right ( i hope they are right, but everything else is working just fine )

There is enough ram/hdd on server

At first time all worked ( nothing very special was done with SP after that )

Same error on different browsers ( IE/FF/CH ), on different PC including server itself

Master pages are in their original state

IIS reset, recycle, mumbo-jumbo, blob cache cleaning

No matter on what web page or in any other place ( like adding it into list view page ), on root and sub-sites, with any possible urls ( intranet, internet, deep space or whatever possible url ). Also have tried in another site collection ( create new ), even in administration page ( Distribution groups page can be edited for some reason ).

Well, it could be a solution to just destroy SP in some horrible way, but its our production server ... on test server everything is fine of course.

In Fiddler i've catched next SOAP responce error :

---soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.-Error occurred.

Very informative message "error occurred", well, NOW we know it was error :)

Its responce from /_vti_bin/WebPartPages.asmx

Adding debug options to web.config in sts or vti_bin gives nothing, no log created and no additional information on exception.

From that point i really don't know what to do ...

Hope for Your help :)
Thanks))

Comment: Im all alone in this world? :(

Comment: A similar question was posted here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090807/sharepoint-using-a-content-editor-web-part-this-error-occurredcannot-retrieve] Because of the complexity of SharePoint it seems that you may have to try several approaches to figure out a solution.

Comment: has anyone found a correct answer to this question?!?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this same issue myself, after searching everywhere I found that if I use IE I have to use the developer tools, hit F12 and select version 8 in the upper right corner of the developer tool window, once that was done I was able to make and save the changes and they still worked when I changed my browser setting back to version 10, apparently there is a bug in the newer versions of IE that cause issues like these.